# Compute the integral $\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\mathrm d \theta}{\sqrt{\sin \theta}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

Compute the Riemann integral

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\mathrm d \theta}{\sqrt{\sin \theta}}$$

It seems very difficult, I don't know how to go ahead.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It will require elliptic integrals. Are you familiar with those?

Comment: The title doesn't match the question.

Comment: @DavidH I know a  little of elliptic integrals, not much

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks!

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{t \equiv \sin\pars{\theta}:}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over \root{\sin\pars{\theta}}}&
=\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/2}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
=\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/4}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{1}t^{-3/4}\pars{1 - t}^{-1/2}\,\dd t
=\half\,{\rm B}\pars{{1 \over 4},\half}
\end{align}
where $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y}}$ is the
[Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over \root{\sin\pars{\theta}}}}&
> =\half\,{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{3/4}}
> ={\root{\pi} \over 2}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/4} \over \pi/\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1/4}\sin\pars{\pi/4}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over 2\root{\pi}}\,{\root{2} \over 2}\,\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{1 \over 4}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 4}\,\root{2 \over \pi}\Gamma^{\,2}\pars{1 \over 4}}
> \approx 2.6221
> \end{align}
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the [Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and we used well known properties of it.

Comment: @DavidH That was unexpected. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I just liked how you managed it without elliptic integrals, and fairly quickly to boot.

Answer (score 8):

Put $x=\sin^2\theta$ then $\sqrt{\sin\theta}=x^{1/4}$ and $\theta=\arcsin\sqrt{x}$ hence
$$\eqalign{
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\sin\theta}}&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}\frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-x}}\cr
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1x^{-3/4}(1-x)^{-1/2}dx\cr
&=\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/4)}\cr
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\Gamma^2(1/4)}{\Gamma(1/4)\Gamma(3/4)}\cr
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{\sin(\pi/4)}{\pi}\Gamma^2(1/4)\cr
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}} \Gamma^2(1/4).
}
$$
wher $B$ and $\Gamma$ are the well-known Eulerian Functions.

Answer (score 3):

In general we have

$$2\int^{\pi/2}_0\sin^{2x-1}(\theta)\cos^{2y-1}(\theta)\,d\theta=B(x,y)$$

Comment: What is $B(x,y)$, the Beta function?

Comment: @MTurgeon, yes.